# Warnings on Visual C++ Standard Library

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying out Visual Studio at the time. I created a simple hello world program and activated all warnings (**EnableAllWarnings (/Wall)**). But I was suprised by the fact that the standard library seemed to produce alot of warnings (561 on hello world).

[image: Warnings in VS]

Is there a way to turn of the warnings for the standard library? Or to exclude a specific file from warnings? I'd really like to use /Wall but not with getting thousands of warnings.

(I'm using Visual Studio 2010)

Comment: Off-topic: "standard" with a `d`! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this article in MSDN: [/w, /Wn, /WX, /Wall, /wln, /wdn, /wen, /won (Warning Level)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx)

For most development projects setting the warning level to 'Level 3' is sufficient. But if you are so concerned set it to 'Level 4'.

The article also has links to warnings that are off by default.

Comment: I guess I'll use Level 4 then. I'm still wondering why they didn't write warning free ehader files.